# visual-studio invalid UTF-8 in comment[clang-dianostic-invalid-utf8]

Tags: visual-studio, utf-8, visual-studio-2022

Visaul Studio 2022 in Windows 11 chinese version

The default format of the file is GB2312.

It remind in chinese comment and some blank space "invalid UTF-8 in comment[clang-dianostic-invalid-utf8]"

I don't know how to fix it, the code is right and normal execute.

is the comment come from Visaul Studio or plugin "Sonarlint" "Resharper" "CodeMind"?

Thank you for your help.

[image]

```
LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProc(HWND hwnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam){
HDC hdc;
PAINTSTRUCT ps;
HFONT hFont, hFontOld;
static BOOL IsCalcStr = TRUE;           // 只在第一次WM_PAINT消息中计算s_iCol1、s_iCol2、s_iHeight
static int s_iCol1, s_iCol2, s_iHeight; // 第一列、第二列字符串的最大宽度，字符串高度
static int s_cxClient, s_cyClient;      // 客户区宽度、高度
static int s_iVscrollPos;               // 垂直滚动条当前位置
TCHAR szBuf[10];
int y;

switch (uMsg)
{
case WM_CREATE:
    // 设置垂直滚动条的范围和初始位置
    SetScrollRange(hwnd, SB_VERT, 0, NUMLINES - 1, FALSE);
    SetScrollPos(hwnd, SB_VERT, s_iVscrollPos, TRUE);
    return 0;
```

Comment: Please [*do not* use (sole) images of code/data/errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/3439404) in your [mcve].
Copy the actual text, paste it into the question, then format it as code. Post a hexadecimal dump in case of (partially) binary content. Are you sure that your comments start with (doubled) `/` (U+002F,  *Solidus*)? BTW, all my (similar) problems are gone after switching to [UTF-8 Everywhere](https://utf8everywhere.org/)…

Comment: Thx，it's software or character encoding display question not the code question，so I upload the images shows where it is. I edit it again like you said.I don't know what you mean "Post a hexadecimal dump in case of (partially) binary content."

Comment: @JosefZ The project is come from other person where encoding is  default GB2312,  When I new a project it's default utf-8 (BOM), the comment disappear! ^_^ Thx

Comment: @kingdelee the default encoding for almost anything by now is UTF8, so people *don't* have to bother about encodings and conversions. That's what the error is complaining about. By selecting a localized codepage you'll get into trouble if you try use any text that isn't either Chinese or in the 7-bit US-ASCII range. You won't be able to handle English words like *naïve*

Comment: Windows itself uses Unicode no matter the version. What was erroneously called the "system locale" in the past is actually the default encoding for non-Unicode applications.

Answer (score 1):

I guess, this is your ReSharper parameter called `clang-diagnostic-invalid-utf8`.
In **C++** ReSharper mode there is pin `invalid-utf8 clang diagnostic`. **In others languages modes maybe they called similar**, but maybe don't.

You can just search similar parameter in option of ReSharper (just search `utf8`) and remove mark from that item. If you don't need these remindes, of course.